# `TabView` and `tabViewStyle(.page)` not navigating as expected

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I've been experimenting with `TabView` and `tabViewStyle` and I've run into a problem with my code I can't figure out.

In the code below, when the app opens up on my device I start on the `HomeScreen()` (as expected) but if I tap on `Profile` in the top bar, the tab navigation doesn't happen. The `Profile` text turns red (indicating that `pageIndex` has been updated), but for reasons I can't figure out, the `TabView` isn't updating accordingly.

BUT, if I open the app and tap on `Settings` in the top bar, the tab navigation happens as expected.

Swiping works as expected, no issues there.

Have I missed something obvious?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Copy code into xcode
2. Run on simulator / canvas / device
3. Tap `Profile` (don't swipe or tap anything else)
4. `Profile` will turn red, but the page won't be animated left to the `Profile` screen.
5. If you tap `Settings` or swipe any direction, tapping `Profile` will work as expected.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeNavigation2: View {
    @State var pageIndex = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: self.$pageIndex) {
                // The screen to the "left" of the Home screen
                ProfileScreen()
                    .tag(0)
                
                // The screen we want the app to load on
                HomeScreen()
                    .tag(1)
                
                // The screen to the "right" of the Home screen
                SettingsScreen()
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            pageIndex = 0
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Profile")
                            .foregroundColor(pageIndex == 0 ? .red : .primary)
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            pageIndex = 2
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Settings")
                            .foregroundColor(pageIndex == 2 ? .red : .primary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct ProfileScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Profile screen")
    }
}

private struct HomeScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Home screen")
    }
}

private struct SettingsScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Settings screen")
    }
}
```

Edit:

I've taken some of the suggestions and amended the code as such:

```swift
struct SwipeNavigation2: View {
    @State var pageIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: self.$pageIndex) {
                ProfileScreen()
                    .tag(0)
                
                HomeScreen()
                    .tag(1)
                
                SettingsScreen()
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .onAppear {
                pageIndex = 1
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            pageIndex = 0
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Profile")
                            .foregroundColor(pageIndex == 0 ? .red : .primary)
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            pageIndex = 2
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Settings")
                            .foregroundColor(pageIndex == 2 ? .red : .primary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Here's a recording from my simulator (Xcode14.1), on an iPhone 14. You'll see once the recording starts, I tap on `Profile` (which turns it red), but the `TabView` isn't moving me to the correct page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uJ0c.jpg

**Edit 2:**

It gets weirder. I've tested the following devices in XCode simulator:

- iPhone 13 (doesn't work)
- iPhone 13 Mini (doesn't work)
- iPhone 14 (doesn't work)
- iPhone 14 Pro (works)
- iPhone 14 Pro Max (works)

Comment: Might be `SwiftUI` bug. For a quick fix, you can initialize `pageIndex` with `0` and set it to `1` in `onAppear`.

Comment: @NiravD Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, and unfortunately it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Comment: if you attach the `.onAppear` to the `TabView` it works for me.

Comment: correction: works in preview but not in simulator !?

Comment: @ragavanmonke I have tested in `XCode14` with Simulator `14ProMax` its working for me with the change I have suggested. Make sure you have set the default value to 0 and then in onAppear set it to 1. If its still not working please let me know Xcode version and iOS version you are working on.

Comment: @NiravD I've added an edit to my original post with the suggestions and a recording from simulator (xcode 14.1, iphone 14) that shows it's not working.

Comment: Filed a bugreport to Apple. Having the same issue here: https://github.com/fl034/TabViewPageStyleBugTest . The marked answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Going on iOS 17 now and this is still a bug. I have filed it with Apple. Also put it into openRadar here: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5534256096870400

Comment: @AndreiT could you try my workaround? it might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `onAppear` modifier on the tab with the index set at init (in your case the Profile View.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AdamView: View {
    @State var pageIndex: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           TabView(selection: self.$pageIndex) {
            Text("Profile")
                .onAppear {
                    pageIndex = 1
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            Text("Home")
                .tag(1)
            
            Text("Settings")
                .tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        pageIndex = 0
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Profile")
                        .foregroundColor(pageIndex == 0 ? .red : .primary)
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        pageIndex = 2
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Settings")
                        .foregroundColor(pageIndex == 2 ? .red : .primary)
                }
            }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Another solution is to use the `task` modifier instead. With the task, you can keep the onAppear on the TabView but I noticed we see the Profile View for a very short time before showing the Home tab.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on iOS 16.1. Also this solution seems very dangerous since SwiftUI calls onAppear multiple times. Even if another tab is being shown. I think the behaviour originates from UIPageController what could being used under the hood, where always the next page was being preloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, when I was initializing the view with the third tab selected and then changing the selection binding to the first one.

See this minimal example: https://gist.github.com/fl034/970869befe8f8a3a4947ea97a6fb046d

Fixed it by introducing an extra property for a initial selected tab and a minimal delay. That way every view will be loaded and tapping

```
.onAppear {
    if let initiallySelectedTab {
        self.initiallySelectedTab = nil
        // Delay is needed to prevent SwiftUI bug where tapping the first tab wouldn't
        // change views. This way every view will be loaded.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.selectedTab = initiallySelectedTab
        }
    }
}
```

I also filed a bug at Apple (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com)

#### Update

Here's the updated minimal example with my workaround. Tested on iOS 16.4.

https://gist.github.com/fl034/8f318cf9c2de64f6354bdee7f5c57f31

Comment: I really want to try this answer, but I couldn't figure it out, could you put it in the minimal example, please?

Comment: @Mia added a link to the updated file :)

Comment: Thank you! It does work on your scenario! But not on mine ;(

Answer (score 0):

If we place tabItem for each view in the tabview then this bug would go away.

PS. These tabs won't be shown since the tabViewStyle is set to page.

[minimal example](https://github.com/MiaShopgal/SwipingTap/tree/main)

```
TabView(selection: self.$pageIndex) {

            ProfileScreen()
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem { Label ( "dummy label",
                                    systemImage : "gearshape.fill" ) }
            
            HomeScreen()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem { Label ( "label won't appear",
                                    systemImage : "gearshape.fill" ) }                    
            
            SettingsScreen()
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem { Label ( "since the style is page",
                                    systemImage : "gearshape.fill" ) }

        }
```